# error during maas install

Tags: maas, postgresql

During install of maas ISO 16.04.2 on vSphere, I get the below error.

```
An error occurred while installing the database:
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the
server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas? A regular install of ubuntu server works fine.

Comment: I get the same error. In the syslog, I see that policy-rc.d returned 101 when trying to run 'restart postgresql', and after that it says that pam_systemd failed to connect to system bus (no such file or directory).

Answer (score 0):

While I never did figure out exactly what caused this error, I was able to get a maas up and running. I created it on a vlan that was not as locked down and increased the size of the disk space.